# Should I run F# in SqlClr?

Tags: c#, sql-server, f#, sqlclr

I need to run .Net code in Sql and I'm trying to decide between F# and C#. 
I'm doing more and more code in F# nowadays so if it's not too impractical, I'd like it to be F#.

Is it possible to coerce VS2010 to deploy my F# assemblies (and their references) to Sql Server, in the same nice way a C# project does?

Would you recommend/not recommend running F# in Sql? Why?

**EDIT:** 
I agree that the language is better, that is not the question. I was mainly wondering if anyone had experience with using F# in SqlClr and specifically if the tools can offer a simple workflow for development, i.e. Deploy in VS2010.

**EDIT 2:** 
I'm experimenting with this, and registering manually is downright painful. Besides `CREATE ASSEMBLY` you have to register each function, sp, aggregate etc. You also have to drop them in the right order first, if they exist, lest you get a `DROP ASSEMBLY failed because 'Nibbler' is referenced by object 'Hello'.`

I then had the idea to use a C# project as a front end and have this project reference an F# project, just to have all this deploying taken care of automatically. Turns out you can only reference other C#/VB Sql Clr projects, or assemblies that are already referenced in Sql. This could still simplify deployment though, as all creation/deletion of functions etc would be handled automatically. Then, for deploying from test to production, I would just generate scripts from all the stuff that is registered in my test environment.

PS. I also tried fiddling with the .fsproj file, diffing with the .csproj of a C# Clr project, to enable deployment to no avail.

Comment: You could tell us why you might be sceptical of doing so, to get your ideas.

Comment: I can't think of anything *other* than the language that is different in this context. The deployment is only different from within VS, but if you're using `CREATE ASSEMBLY` to deploy, it's the same. What else is there?

Comment: @Daniel - Re 'What else is there': I don't know. In theory there should be no other problems. I'm just curious if someone had actually used F# on SQL for real. In theory, practice and theory are the same. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have trouble with FSharp.Core and other references in the SQL CLR context, you could try the `--standalone` [compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) to cause external references to be embedded in the assembly that you deploy to SQL Server.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea either! I've been wanting a linker for C# for ages. :)

Comment: Accepted as answer. Other parts of the project are already in F# and it makes sense to also use F# here, so I'm going with F#, compiled with --standalone.

Comment: Update... I was using the dll from other projects as well, which caused problems when using --standalone. In short, types in FSharp.Core are not the same as those in my --standalone compiled dll.. Because of this, I'm not using --standalone.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend coding your CLR UDFs/procedures in F# for much the same reason I'd recommend coding almost *anything* in F# (see the numerous F# vs C# questions on SO). I can't think of a reason to prefer C# for *anything*. I haven't tried deploying assemblies to SQL Server using VS, but `CREATE ASSEMBLY` works just fine...and works the same, regardless of programming language.

Comment: +1 I agree with @Maurico Use F# if it's the best tool for the job.

Comment: I'm a huge F# fan and I work only with it, but there are several scenarios in which you'd prefer C#. Sometimes just because F#'s support for XAML (and the like) is limited and sometimes because F# was designed for specific tasks (for example, working with pointers on a big image is easier with C#).

Comment: I'll bet it's possible to even work with pointers painlessly in F# (see the `NativePtr` module - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340434.aspx).

Comment: @Ramon - regarding F# being designed for specific tasks, I'd argue it's as much of a Swiss army knife language as any available today. To the extent that statement can be made for *any* programming language, it seems to apply even less to F#.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, the language supports most things just fine. The tools are way behind though. Lets hope for a proper CodeDOM in vNext to further F# adoption.

Comment: It's worth noting: the tools are behind...those for imperative languages, but on par or better than many functional languages (especially the IDE and debugger).